# JSF composite component validation

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I want to create composite component and attach some validators to it's children, but I want message from validation to be attached to composite component, not to it's child.

In the page using the composite component I want something like this:

```
<zzz:mycomponent id="my" />
<h:message for="my" />
```

Now it doesn't work, because message is for component's child, not composite component itself. How to make it for whole component?

Or even better, I would like to add validator to composite component, like:

```
<zzz:mycomponent id="my" validator="#{bean.validateComposite}" />
```

And receiver something like booleans array as value, because inside composite component there are `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` elements. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe very late to respond on this question but this is how I should do it:

```
<zzz:mycomponent id="my">
   <f:event type="postValidate" listener="#{bean.doValidation}"/>
</zzz:mycomponent>
```

The doValidation is then called after the validation of the childs in the 'container'.  The method llooks like this:

```
public void doValidation(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    ...
}
```

And you have 2 options in that method:

- Access the child components (event.getComponent().getChildren() ) and do whatever you want to do with the values submitted on those childs.
- Or loop over the FacesMessages and reallocate the clientId so that they are placed on your container component (id = my)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the next code inside your composite definition

```
      <cc:interface>
          .....
          <cc:editableValueHolder name="attName" targets="Idcomponent" /><!--It allows to acces to the composite-->
          <cc:facet name="textMessage"/>                                 <!--Define the Facet-->
      </cc:interface>
      <cc:implementation id="#{cc.attrs.id}" >
          ......
          <h:inputText id="Idcomponent" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" required="#{cc.attrs.required}"/>
          <cc:renderFacet name="textMessage"/>
      </cc:implementation>
```

You can use in the JSF page

```
      <zzz:textBox id="txbTest" label="#{}" value="#{}" >
           <f:validateLongRange for="attName" minimum="-10" maximum="10"/>
           <f:facet name="textMessage">
                <h:message for="value" style="color: blue"/>
            </f:facet>
      </zzz:textBox>
```

Or another option could be :

```
      <zzz:textBox id="txbTest" label="#{}" value="#{}" validator="#{bean.yourValidateMethod}" >
           <f:facet name="textMessage">
                <h:message for="value" style="color: blue"/>
            </f:facet>
      </zzz:textBox>
```